# Eclipse, assembly appears infinite whilst using DIssembler?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am using the dissembler view in the debugging section of Eclipse for C++.

1) Is there any way to see the assembly language without debugging, but perhaps just compiling/running?

2) When I click debug and I look at the dissembler window, if i scroll down the assembly produced (for a hello world application) appears infinite. When I go to scroll back to the top it never lets me and keeps producing more code. It had thousands of the exact same line:

```
add %al,(%rax)
```

Answer (score 1):

"g++ -S myfile.cpp" will generate an assembly language source file for you.

I believe that "add %al,(%rax)" corresponds to binary "00 00" - perhaps you're "disassembling" a region of memory that's been zero'ed out?